# Can't get the double quotes right

Tags: php

I have the following which works fine:

```
header("Location: /index.php", true, 300);
```

but I want the filename to be dynamic, i.e.

```
header("Location: /" . $_SESSION['initiating_url']);
```

This works fine, however, I still need the `, true, 300` at the end, which I can't seem to figure out:

```
header("Location: /" . $_SESSION['initiating_url'] . "\"", true, 300);
header("Location: /" . $_SESSION['initiating_url'] . """, true, 300);
```

but they just don't seem to work correctly.  The bottom one gives me syntax error in my editor. and the second to last example doesn't redirect at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to add an explicit *closing* `"` when [concatenating strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
header("Location: /" . $_SESSION['initiating_url'], true, 300);
```

For clarity:

```
$path = 'home';
echo "Location: /" . $path;          // Location: /home
echo "Location: /home";              // Location: /home
echo "Location: /" . $path . "\"";   // Location: /home"
echo "\"Location: /" . $path . "\""; // "Location: /home"
```

Comment: Though I don't understand what you say with explicit and implied, your answer is correct. :)

Comment: @nl-x, the OP believes they need to explicitly quote a string, i.e. `"string"`. But the *closing quote* is not necessary when using string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the advantage of having the string parsed to do this instead:

```
header("Location: /{$_SESSION['initiating_url']}", true, 300);
```

If you ever *need* to join strings, you should use single quotes because they are a bit faster  (they dont get parsed or something) like this: `$foo='World'; echo 'Hello\n'.$foo;`. Thats also good if you dont want the \n to be turned into an escape character where `$foo='World'; echo "Hello\n$foo";` would parse it. (totally off-topic but helpful I guess)

Comment: Yes! Too many people seem to think that concatenation is the only way to have variables inside text. String parsing makes for text that is easier to read, in most cases anyway.